# How to dynamically refer to dataframes in a for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dynamic, reference, pandas

I am very new to python and it's probably a simple question, but I cannot seem to find a solution.

I have several pandas data frames with names going like:
output_1, output_2, ..., output_n

I want to sum their lengths (as in the number of their rows) and I came up with something like this:

```
sum =0
for num in range(1,n):
    nameframe="output_"+str(num)
    sum+=nameframe.shape[0]
```

The problem is that Python sees nameframe as a string, not as the name of a dataframe.

Looking around I found a potential solution:

```
sum =0
for num in range(1,n):
    x = globals()["output_urls_%s" % num] 
    sum+=x.shape[0]
```

This seems to work, however the usage of globals() seem to be very discouraged.
Therefore, what is the most pythonic way to achieve my purpose?

Comment: You're in a messed up situation that requires a lot of work because you didn't stick with standards to begin with. Instead of manually creating all your data frames and giving them df_id like names, create them in a loop and stick them into a list. Then you could iterate over that list.

Comment: you can use `nameframe = eval("output_"+str(num))` in the loop, but I agree with @FooBar you should be storing these as a list upon creation, or if you want to keep names use a dictionary.

Comment: OK, thank you. I indeed inserted the data frames in a list. It's much more tidy and easy to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most pythonic way would probably be to store your dataframes in a list.  E.g.,

```
dfs = [output_1, output_2, ...]
df_length = sum(x.shape[0] for x in dfs)
```

Alternatively, you could look at storing your data in a combined pandas data structure, assuming they are all related in some way.  E.g., if each dataframe is a different group, you could set a MultiIndex on the combined frame, like

```
df = pd.concat([output_1, output_2, ...], keys=['group_a', 'group_b', ..])
```

Then you could just take the length of the combined frame.

Comment: Your second line can be simplified to `df_length = sum(len(x) for x in dfs)`

Comment: Thanks, as suggested throughout the comments, storing the data frames in a list is the best solution.